# Why the pragma encoding="UTF-16" not working in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have tested the command `PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-16";` in sqlite command prompt.
It is able to change the encoding but while running same as `db.rawQuery("PRAGMA encoding = \"UTF-16\";",null);`in android not able to convert the encoding. So guys anybody know what is the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Even if it worked, it would not have any effect on the data as seen by the app. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: I need to join two database and run a query on it but now I am not able to do it because I have two database in different encoding. the UTF-16 database I am getting from back end that I cant change.

Comment: The DB encoding makes no difference when joining.

Comment: I am not able to attach the DBs which are different encoding plz tell me how to join them. I tried so many times and failed. Thanks

Comment: If you have a problem with attaching DBs, maybe you should [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that …

Answer (score 0):

[Be aware](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding):

> It is not possible to change the text encoding of a database after it has been created and any attempt to do so will be silently ignored.